# How do I set up a try catch exception for IndexOutOfRangeException with an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

I have a method that requires user input of an char that relates to an array. I need to use a try catch exception statement to trigger some form of an exception preferably a `IndexOutOfRangeException`. If the user does not enter the correct char they need to be prompted to input a char again.

```
private static double dataEntry(string location, int num, int month, Mural[] murals)
{
    string entryString;
    bool isValid;
    int x;
    char code;
    double tot = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nEntering {0} jobs:", location);
    x = 0;
    while (x < num)
    {
        tot += murals[x].Price;
        Console.Write("Enter customer name >> ");
        murals[x].Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Mural options are:");
        for (int y = 0; y < Mural.muralCodes.Length; ++y)
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}   {1}", Mural.muralCodes[y], Mural.muralTypes[y]);
        Console.Write("       Enter mural style code >> ");
        entryString = Console.ReadLine();
        isValid = false;
        while (!isValid)
        {
            try
            {
                code = char.Parse(entryString);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong format");
                Console.Write("       Enter mural style code >> ");
                entryString = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong format");
                Console.Write("       Enter mural style code >> ");
                entryString = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!char.TryParse(entryString, out code))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong format");
                    Console.Write("       Enter mural style code >> ");
                    entryString = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    murals[x].Code = code;
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
        }
        ++x;
    }
    return tot;
}
```

Comment: You "throw" an exception. Sadly I don't understand c#, but in java you would do: `throw new IndexOutOfRangeException()`.

Comment: @MistressDavid - your syntax is perfectly valid in C# too..

Answer (score 1):

You should use function `Char.TryParse` like this

```
char output;

if (char.TryParse(whatUserEntered, output))
{
  // Char is in output.
}
else
{
    //Bad entry by user.
}
```

Comment: it is for an assignment and i have to use try catch

Comment: Try Parse do not raise exception when bad entry is done by user. So no need to add try catch.

Comment: it is for an assignment and i have to use the try catch

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to conditionally trigger an exception. Use this code:

```
if(/* not valid or out of bounds */) {
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Comment: yes but i need to do it like this ... if user input is not valid or out of bounds trigger the exception ... does that make since?

Comment: I couldn't define what would be in the if statement since i dont know what would be considered out of bounds or invalid

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the msdn reference below, rewrite your code and post back any more problems.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173165(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're really *required* to use try/catch, and you want to reprompt the user, try this. I'll explain it all so you understand what's going on ... since it's homework and all.

You're catching multiple exceptions, but there's no need since you're doing the same thing in each one. Just catch and.. do nothing. There's really nothing to *do* in the catch statement, but at least your program doesn't terminate. In the real world, you'd notify the user, or log the error or something.

While `char.Parse` fails and throws an exception, your logic will never reach the next two lines (`murals[x]...` and `isValid = true`), and your loop will repeat until the user enters a valid character. At that point, isValid is true and exit the `while` loop.

```
bool isValid = false;

while (!isValid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong format");
    Console.Write("       Enter mural style code >> ");
    entryString = Console.ReadLine();

    try
    {
        code = char.Parse(entryString);

        murals[x].Code = code;
        isValid = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        // Just ignore the error
        // Bad practice, which is why others are suggesting Char.TryParse
    }
}
```